# Leaving company and wiping personal data

Tags: contract-law, privacy, non-disclosure

I am new here please help and answer my question.
In case you are leaving the company, you worked for, if you wipe your personal data such an email you logged on or data like the logs of the websites you visited from the PC, Laptop or cellphone that owned by the company have you violate the law?
**The second question is**: I would like to say that the reference to the prohibition of the personal use of the assets of the company in the NDA contract not in a separate contract, can this issue violate authenticity of this clause?
**PS:** the reasons for wiping that is because that company can not abuse data.
**PS:** In the NDA there is a paragraph that says you can not use company properties for a personal issue.

Comment: My "educated guess" is that deletion of your personal data does not violate the law. However, you might want to specify your jurisdiction because each legislation can provide different levels of protection to the employee or to the employer. Your second question is unclear. Use of company's property for personal matters and a NDA are legally unrelated to each other even if they are covered in the same document.

Comment: You are not "violating the law", you may be violating the contract you have with the company, but no laws are broken (unless you delete something that could be considered criminal, like company IP). In order to determine this, we would have to see the terms of your contract.

Comment: @RonBeyer In any competently run company, company IP will be backed up somewhere else.  If something important was only in OP's email, and OP was not personally delinquent in filing it,any court case would bring up corporate negligence.

Comment: @DavidThornley You would be surprised about the companies that are not backing everything up, and I'm not just referencing email. Also, people in the IT department have access to those things and may maliciously delete backups. Even backups have a delay, so deleting something that is backed up doesn't mean the company doesn't lose quite a bit of work.

Comment: @RonBeyer breaching a contract is “violating the law”, the law requires you to fulfil your contracts- it’s just not a crime in most jurisdictions (don’t breach a contract in Arabia, for example).

Comment: @RonBeyer Having been chewed out for overwriting the production version of a program (which had been changed while in production with nothing corresponding in source control or the development or test environments), I'm not actually surprised about what's not backed up.  However, if valuable company IP exists only in one person's mailbox, I'm claiming negligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is on a company owned computer it’s their data - not yours. If you delete data you don’t own without authority then that’s illegal in most jurisdictions.

Before you leave you are clearly authorised to use the device so if you are authorised to delete it depends on the data. For example, you can probably delete personal communications but probably not business ones.

Notwithstanding, the company is bound by relevant privacy laws if the data is personal so it cannot be (legitimately) abused.